# xrandr: cannot find output 0x49

Tags: 18.04, monitor, xrandr, external-monitor

I cannot configure my Samsung U28E590D using xrandr. It works fine under Windows and using the Gnome control center it mostly works fine - but I want to use i3. xrandr seems to be able to detect the display as it's lists it when I run `xrandr` without any params. But then, when I try to configure it, it gives me various errors, from my understanding all coming from it's inability to find the display.

Here it's listed as `DP-2-2`:

```
❯ xrandr --prop 
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 5760 x 2160, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 173mm
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff0006af3d1300000000
        26170104951f11780287e5a456509e26
        0d505400000001010101010101010101
        010101010101143780b8703824401010
        3e0035ad100000180000000f00000000
        00000000000000000020000000fe0041
        554f0a202020202020202020000000fe
        004231343048414e30312e33200a007a
    scaling mode: Full aspect 
        supported: Full, Center, Full aspect
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
   1920x1080     60.05*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    aspect ratio: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, 4:3, 16:9
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    aspect ratio: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, 4:3, 16:9
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
DP-2-2 connected 3840x2160+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 607mm x 345mm
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
   3840x2160     60.00*+  30.00    29.97  
   2560x1440     59.95  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-2-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
DP-2-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
```

When I try to configure it:

```
❯ xrandr --output DP-2-2 --mode 2560x1440 --primary 
xrandr: cannot find mode 2560x1440       

❯ xrandr --output DP-2-2                           
xrandr: cannot find output 0x49
```

I have the Lenovo T450s with the Intel graphics here and connect the display via a original docking station and display port.

```
❯ lspci -v | perl -ne '/VGA/../^$/ and /VGA|Kern/ and print'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

❯ lspci -nnk | grep "VGA\|'Kern'\|3D\|Display" -A2 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 [8086:1616] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Lenovo HD Graphics 5500 [17aa:5036]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

With other monitors, xrandr works fine

---

I would also accept alternatives to xrandr, as long as it's not too much effort to get them working with i3.

Comment: `xrandr` is not showing the EDID data from that port, that raise suspicion about physical connection